# How to remove whitespace from a formatted number with Regex Table in GTM

Tags: regex, google-tag-manager

I have a variable in Google Tag Manager with formatted digits that I want to strip from whitespace using the Regex Table
The numbers look like 3 500 000, and I want 3500000.

What should I type in the pattern and output?

The input is 3 500 000

The output should be 3500000

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I had the "Enable Capture Groups and Replace Functionality" unchecked in options.
I just added `\s*`to pattern and i worked